# How to upload video using AFNetworking on Server

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking-3

I,m trying to upload video using afnetworking and my code is below in response it return nil url please let me know if you want any other detail . i don,t know where is my mistake.

```
{
        // add hud to show sending image
        [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];


        NSString *format;
        format=@"video/mp4";

        myDict1 = @{@"user_id”:””,
                    @"timezone”:””,
                    @"friend_id”:””,
                    @"message_type”:””,
                    @"message":"",
                    @"language_id”:””
                    };

        AFHTTPSessionManager *manager=[AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
        NSString* webService=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/send_messages",WEB_SERVICE_URL_BETA];

        [manager POST:webService parameters:myDict1 constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData>  _Nonnull formData)
         {
             [formData appendPartWithFileData:picturedata  name:@"file" fileName:@"testvideo.mov" mimeType:@"video/quickTime"];



                     } progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * Nonnull task, id  Nullable responseObject) {

             if ([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[responseObject valueForKey: @"status"] ] isEqualToString:@"1"])
             {

             }
             else
             {

             }
         }
              failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask  _Nullable task, NSError  _Nonnull error) {
                  NSLog(@"Failure %@",error);
                               }];

          }
```

Comment: code seems right.. can you share complete error message.. or may be any request paramtr key mismatch

Comment: Hello Sir , 
There is no error are in result , but issue is when i hit Api to and upload video to server , after that it return with null URl in response.

Comment: I think the issue that i am facing is that the video data are not sent properly to server or not append correctly. So that it return Null .

Comment: have you checked, your nsdata and videourl is proper?  
  NSURL *videoUrl=(NSURL*)[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
  NSData * picturedata = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:videoUrl];

Comment: Thanks @VarinderSingh Its working Now. My old code is also same which also start working. Again Thanks for Your help :)

Comment: wlcm brother..what was the issue?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145510/discussion-between-varinder-singh-and-manvir-singh).